# MySQL, PHP: How to "slide down" records by specific row?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table with "position" row. Basically a set of records that have their own ID, description and title (and position) rows.

Position is unique for each record and no two records can have same position. As you create new records, its position is created by selecting max position value and adding 1 to it.

The problem is when you *delete* a record a position "gap" forms in the table. Let's say records had 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 position values, you delete the 4th and it becomes 1, 2, 3, 5.

I want this row to "slide" down, so it becomes 1, 2, 3, 4. If 2nd record was deleted, it should become 1, 2, 3 (instead of 1, 3, 4).

Also, if there's much complicated position stack such as 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, _, 8, where _ is deleted, then it should respect the unordered 1, 3, 2, 4 part and become 1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7.

[image]

Comment: 1. use a primary key 2. without a primary key you will have concurrency issues 3. why do you want contiguous numbers?

Comment: @Mihai I already have `id` as a primary key.

Comment: @Mihai There is a set of elements (records) that is displayed on the website via PHP (`SELECT * FROM 'products' WHERE ('position' >= ". $start .") AND ('position' < ". $offset .") ORDER BY 'position' ASC";`). You can set a position of a given element, but only if new position is occupied (kinda swap with other element)

Comment: You will need to run a JOB every time you add a record. It will be extremely costy on bigger tables, since it will have to check and update every single row every time. Perhaps you could think of a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you delete the position you know the value(which position you are deleting).Then fetch all values, & after the particular position, that you have deleted, decrease by 1. i.
if your stack is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 & your are deleting 7, then count total stack which is= 9 now run for() loop,starting from 7 : update table set position = position-1 where position =7.

But it is not a good solution.